SharePoint Online JSON tile custom formatting - setValue updates not shown
I am creating a custom tile view for a SharePoint Online list. I have buttons on the tile view which use the setValue action to update the item. This works, but the change is not displayed immediately - I have to manually refresh to page. Without refreshing the page, there is no indication the button did anything.
What is the best way to get the update to immediately show? Can I automatically refresh the page after updating the item?

{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 273,
  "width": 254,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
                },
                "txtContent": "[!Title.DisplayName]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Title]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent",
                  "role": "heading",
                  "aria-level": "3"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Title] == '', '–', [$Title])"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
                },
                "txtContent": "[!ContentType.DisplayName]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$ContentType]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content "
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$ContentType] == '', '–', [$ContentType])"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
                },
                "txtContent": "[!Status.DisplayName]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Status]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content "
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Status] == '', '–', [$Status])"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
                },
                "txtContent": "Result"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "style": {
                  "display": "=if ([$ContentType] == 'Item1', 'block', 'none')"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "p",
                    "attributes": {
                      "title": "[$Result1]",
                      "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content "
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "display": "=if ([$Result1] != '', 'block', 'none')"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "[$Result1]"
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "style": {
                      "display": "=if ([$Result1] == '', 'block', 'none')"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "button",
                        "txtContent": "Result11",
                        "customRowAction": {
                          "action": "setValue",
                          "actionInput": {
                            "Result1": "Result11",
                            "Status": "Completed"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "elmType": "button",
                        "txtContent": "Result12",
                        "customRowAction": {
                          "action": "setValue",
                          "actionInput": {
                            "Result1": "Result12",
                            "Status": "Completed"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "elmType": "button",
                        "txtContent": "Result13",
                        "customRowAction": {
                          "action": "setValue",
                          "actionInput": {
                            "Result1": "Result13",
                            "Status": "Completed"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "style": {
                  "display": "=if ([$ContentType] == 'Item2', 'block', 'none')"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "p",
                    "attributes": {
                      "title": "[$Result2]",
                      "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content "
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "display": "=if ([$Result2] != '', 'block', 'none')"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "[$Result2]"
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "style": {
                      "display": "=if ([$Result2] == '', 'block', 'none')"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "button",
                        "txtContent": "Result21",
                        "customRowAction": {
                          "action": "setValue",
                          "actionInput": {
                            "Result2": "Result21",
                            "Status": "Completed"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "elmType": "button",
                        "txtContent": "Result22",
                        "customRowAction": {
                          "action": "setValue",
                          "actionInput": {
                            "Result2": "Result22",
                            "Status": "Completed"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "elmType": "button",
                        "txtContent": "Result23",
                        "customRowAction": {
                          "action": "setValue",
                          "actionInput": {
                            "Result2": "Result23",
                            "Status": "Completed"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


Not found any issue.. it's working for me. Please try clearing your browser cache
